# How to use Avro generated schemas with Kafka Connect custom source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I'm developing a custom source connector using Kafka Connect, and I am trying to incorporate Avro support. For this purpose I created some `.avsc` files to describe my key and value schemas and added the `avro-maven-plugin` to my project to automatically create corresponding java classes that I can use in my code.

From the generated classes, I can get the schema as an object of type `org.apache.avro.Schema`.

But the return type of the `poll` method of the source connector is a list of `org.apache.kafka.connect.source.SourceRecord` objects, whose constructor takes schemas as instances of `org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema`, and I simply don't see a straight-forward way to convert one to the other.

So how do I get suitable key/value schema instances that I can then plug into the SourceRecords to be returned from the poll method in my connector?

Am I even on the right track with using the Avro Maven plugin, or should I use something else?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm only familiar with the Kafka Connect framework overall, not the details of writing a connector - but IIUC if you're writing a connector, you shouldn't be needing to do anything with Avro, since that's handled by the _Converter_ downstream. Do either of these resources help? https://opencredo.com/blogs/kafka-connect-source-connectors-a-detailed-guide-to-connecting-to-what-you-love/ https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html

Comment: I already read the pages you linked, they didn't help me. The problem is that I want the schema definitions (i.e. the .avsc files) to live independently from my project. This is supposed to be part of a microservice architecture, and the schemas are kind of an API that the services use to communicate among each other. If I let Kafka Connect generate and register the schemas from my code, then they won't be easily available to other services which might not even be written in Java, so I want to somehow invert the process and make the code follow the schemas.

Comment: Then you need to create a separate project for your schemas and upload them to a Maven service for use in other projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain if this is recommended, however, you may be able to leverage the `AvroData` class provided in the `kafka-connect-avro-converter` library to accomplish the conversion.

The library can be found here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-connect-avro-converter/5.4.1

The source for the class is here:
https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/5.4.1-post/avro-converter/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/avro/AvroData.java

You'd have to instantiate AvroData and then try the `toConnectSchema` function.

Comment: That does work, but it somehow doesn't feel right. I think it would be simpler if there was a way to avoid the avro plugin and just generate the Connect schema definitions from the .avsc files, but there does not seem to be a tool for this. Maybe I'll have to build something along these lines myself to make this work.

Comment: I have accepted this answer, because technically it works, so it is **a** solution, even if not necessarily a **good** one. I decided to go the way outlined in my previous commit: writing a custom maven plugin that directly generates the java code for creating the Connect schemas.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the Avro Schema in Kafka Connect.

Kafka Connect maintains an internal `Struct` and `Schema` class that you should be passing around between `SourceRecord` / `SinkRecord` classes. For example, an HTTP Source could define `int:status`, `string:body` within a `Struct` class.

Basically, let the `Converter` interface is repsonsible for any and all serialization.

Comment: Could you explain it in another way? I thought we need to pass the avro schema that we use to create objects (and for serialization & deserialization) in the property ``` "value.schema":``` but it seems that this results in ```Cannot deserialize value of type `org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema$Type` from String "record": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [STRING, INT16, STRUCT, BOOLEAN, ARRAY, FLOAT64, BYTES, MAP, INT64, INT32, INT8, FLOAT32]``` If i don't provide a schema it returns  ```Could not find any input file(s) to infer schema from.``Can I reuse my .avsc schemas?

Comment: @Georgi I don't know what you're referring to. AvroConverter has no such property called value.schema, but my answer was referring to a custom written connector should only use Schema and Struct classes for internal data representation

Comment: @OneCrickleteer My point is ot send data from JSON files to several kafka topics and use schema registry. I set the value converter to AvroConverter. then i set the auto.register.schemas to true and expected that when I give json to the config, it should generate schema alone and register it in SR. This unfortunately failed with Could not find any input file(s) to infer schema from. Then I found there's value.schema option in kafka-connect jsonspooldir, but if i pass my avro schema to it (escaped and minified) it fails with the mentioned error for String record ... Did i messed up the things?

Comment: @Georgi I suggest creating your own post for that. I've never used the spooldir connector, but I don't think the schema it uses is Avro syntax